# A5 : SQL Mk-2について

Tags: sql, oracle

表題の、データベース用クライアントツールについて質問させてください。

現在私はWindows 10にOracle 12cをインストールし、データベースを触っています。
そしてA5は公私ともによく使っていて、大変便利なツールだと思うのですが最近おかしな現象に悩まされています。

例えば「create table table01(id integer, str varchar2(10));」や「drop table table01;」といった単純なクエリでエラーになってしまうのです。

こんなことが付属のSQL Developerなどでは一切起こりませんので、おそらく権限がどうとかいう問題ではないとは思うのですが…。

ちなみにA5の設定は、

実行位置：「キャレット位置で実行」
SQLの区切り：「スラッシュ"/"のみの行」
SQLファイルのデフォルトエンコーディング：「UTF-8」

です。

またエラーの内容は両方とも「オプション指定されていないか、または無効です」です。

Oracle側では、ユーザ作成後、全ての表領域に対する無制限の表領域割当制限を付与し、「GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO <ユーザー名>」を行い、tnsnamesoraを編集した上でA5からユーザのプラガブルデータベース？に接続しています。

何かOracle側で抜け落ちている手順がございますでしょうか？また、もしそうだとすればSQL Developerで通常のDDL、DML、PL/SQLまでもすべて問題なく動作するのはなぜでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次の問題の可能性があります。

1. キャレット位置が先頭になっていない可能性（自分は、>>>デフォルトを先頭からすべて　にしています）
2. SQLの区切りを「スラッシュのみの行」としているのに、セミコロン;を書いています
   　　SQLの区切りを「;」にするか、;を消してみてください

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事にDDL動くようになりました。もしよろしければもう一点だけ…！！A5でストアド実行した際に、コンソールに文字列を出力するには何かしら設定が必要でしょうか？sql developerでは「set serveroutput on;」を単独で実行すれば良かったのですが、A5だとこれも叶わず…です。Hello, worldしたいだけの場合、設定は必要でしょうか？

Comment: 自分の経験則ですが、A5とOracleのストプロはやや相性が悪いように見えます。コンパイルする際などにハングする可能性が高く、またデバッグ等もいまいちです。そのため、コンパイルはsqlplusを直接使い、デバッグは他の有料ツールを使っています。